# Will SQL Server's UPDATE lock the table in Subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm uisng SQL Server, and have a query which may be accessed by multithreads. In order to return unique rows from each thread, I have this query

```
DECLARE @Guid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();

-- update first to lock what to get
UPDATE [olp].[VendorTaskQueue]
SET VendorTaskStatusId = 20     -- processing
    , [Guid] = @Guid
WHERE VendorTaskQueueId IN (
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) VendorTaskQueueId
    FROM [olp].[VendorTaskQueue]
    WHERE VendorTaskId = @VendorTaskId
        AND VendorTaskStatusId = 10
        AND [Guid] IS NULL
    ORDER BY VendorTaskQueueId
    )

-- only need to return these fields
SELECT [VendorTaskQueueId]
      ,[MessageQueueId]
FROM [olp].[VendorTaskQueue]
WHERE [Guid] = @Guid
    AND VendorTaskStatusId = 20
```

In order to update @BatchSize rows, there is a WHERE Clause. In this above case, the SELECT subquery uses the same table, so I assume it will not cause any issues when multithreads access to it. However, what if this subquery uses another table:

```
DECLARE @Guid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();

-- update first to lock what to get
UPDATE [olp].[VendorTaskQueue]
SET VendorTaskStatusId = 20     -- processing
    , [Guid] = @Guid
WHERE VendorTaskQueueId IN (
    SELECT TOP (@BatchSize) VendorTaskQueueId
    FROM [olp].[*** Another table]
    WHERE VendorTaskId = @VendorTaskId
        AND VendorTaskStatusId = 10
        AND [Guid] IS NULL
    ORDER BY VendorTaskQueueId
    )
......
```

My question is: Will SQL lock [VendorTaskQueue] AND [Another table] since it is an UPDATE? Or, we need to lock [Another table] explicitly?

Thanks

Comment: SQL Server by default uses **row-level locking** - it will not lock **the table** - just those rows that you're updating. This only changes if you have more than 5000 concurrent `UPDATE` operations inside a single transaction - then SQL Server will do a **lock escalation** and lock the entire table

Comment: so it will lock [VendorTaskQueue] but not [Another table]?

Comment: No - it will only lock **some rows** in `[VendorTaskQueue]` (those that match the `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE`) - it will **NOT** lock the entire table (unless - as stated - you're updating more than 5000 rows at once - only then will it lock the whole table)

Comment: For read committed transaction isolation level, which is default,  the "other table" will only has a shared lock during the execution and the shared lock will be released after the select is completed even the update is not committed yet.

Comment: so we will need to lock the 'AnotherTable'. correct?